# вывод каталогов которых нет в базе

Tags: php

Нужно вывсти имена каталогов которых нет в БД, нашел код которая по идее должен это делать, но она выводит просто тупо те каталоги которые в БД забиты

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT id_galery FROM albums");

  $dir = opendir (PATH_ROOT."img/gal/big/");
  echo "Files:\n";
  while ($file = readdir ($dir)) 
  {

    while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
            {
                if($file!=$myrow["id_galery"])
                {

                 echo "<br>".$myrow["id_galery"]."_____Файла НЕТ в базе";

                }
            }
  }
  closedir ($dir);
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()`, по идее, должен быть вынесен из циклов. а во вложенном цикле надо перебирать значения в полученном этой функцией массиве: если значение совпадает, то прервать цикл, а если массив кончился, а совпадения не найдено, вывести сообщение. узнать, кончился ли массив, или цикл был прерван, можно с помощью переменной-флага.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "select id_galery from albums";
$result = mysqli_query($mi, $sql);

$dir = opendir (PATH_ROOT."img/gal/big/");
echo "Files:\n";
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
    $albums[]=$myrow["id_galery"];
}

while ($file = readdir ($dir)) {
    if ($file === '.' || $file === '..')  continue;
    $dirs[] = $file;
}

$res = array_diff($dirs, $albums);

foreach ($res as $f) {
    echo $f," - not found in DB\n";
}
mysqli_close($mi);
```

Comment: огромный жирный лайк=)